# ArXiv number using Biblatex-phys

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-phys

I am using Citavi to organise my sources. One of them is identified by ArXiv, which I want to include in the citation - just as one includes the DOI. Unfortunately, Citavi doesn't export the ArXiv into the .bib file. What's more, I am quite convinced that the (slightly changed) AIP citation style (using biblatex-phys with several adaptions) that I use wouldn't work with it either. Should I just put the ArXiv into the online-adress section?

To clarify: Citavi offers seperate input spaces for Doi, online-adress and ArXiv, although only the first two are exported into the .bib. What the citation style in LaTeX then uses in the end again is a different story.
Thank you!

Comment: arXiv papers now have a DOI, so maybe we can avoid the issue by using that?

Comment: Also old ArXiv papers from 2013 and earlier?

Comment: Not sure, all papers with the "new" ID format appear to have it (I just checked a few random papers from my browser history, some papers were as uploaded as far back as 2006). Those with the old format `math/XXXX` etc. do not appear to have DOIs. **Edit:** OK https://blog.arxiv.org/2022/02/17/new-arxiv-articles-are-now-automatically-assigned-dois/ says all new papers have it and they are going to provide DOIs also for old papers, but this will be done in batches until the end of 2022.

Comment: Ok this might be to late then. I will give it a go nevertheless - thank you!

Comment: But to try to answer the real question (I'm not quite sure I understand): Obviously the best way would be to use the `eprint` field for arXiv links as that is the standard in `biblatex`. If Citavi does not support that (which I find a bit meh, a tool claiming to support `biblatex` should at least try to support its standard data model if there are matching fields available) you need to decide on a case-by-case basis what looks OK and what works for your style. You can try the URL field (which I assume Citavi supports). Or you can use `note` and format everything yourself.

Comment: Do you know where I can look up all the fields that biblatex can work with? I might be able to force Citavi to export the (there) input ArXiv field to the eprint field that biblatex uses.

Comment: The standard `biblatex` fields are documented in §2 of the `biblatex` manual: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

Comment: Thank you! This might already solve my question! Thank you!!

Comment: I managed to print "arXiv-ID: ...". Although the arXiv is not clickable and also, now it bothers me that for the doi only the number is given rather than "DOI: ...".

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with some help from @moewe: At first, one needs to change the export settings in Citavi such that a certain input field is transferred to the ones mentioned here: https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles. Now biblatex shows the arXiv (with hyperlink) with eprint=true in \usepackage[...]{biblatex}.